# Syntax error in SQL statement after upgrading spring-boot-starter-parent from 2.1.1 to 2.3.3

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, h2

In order to test and tweak some internals of Spring Boot, I have a sample Spring Boot project, which I often break, on purpose, and learn new things of its internals.

Now, I have a Spring Boot project, with pom, like:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project xmlns='http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0'
         xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
         xsi:schemaLocation='http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd'>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-application</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and Flyway's migration, with:

```sql
CREATE TABLE PERSON(
    PERSON_ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    PERSON_NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PERSON_SURNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PERSON_AGE BIGINT,
);
```

works fine, until `spring-boot-starter-parent` version is 2.1.1.

I now decided upgrade some dependencies and see, how and what would break (as it quite often happens when working with Spring infrastructure). So, after upgrading `spring-boot-starter-parent` version to 2.3.3, above SQL script started to throw:

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate$FlywayMigrateException: 
Migration V1__initial_schema.sql failed

---------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42001
Error Code : 42001
Message    : Syntax error in SQL statement "CREATE TABLE PERSON(
    PERSON_ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    PERSON_NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PERSON_SURNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PERSON_AGE BIGINT,
    )[*]"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
CREATE TABLE PERSON(
    PERSON_ID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    PERSON_NAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PERSON_SURNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PERSON_AGE BIGINT,
    ) [42001-200]
```

To be frank, even though exception seems clear, at the same time, it does *not* clearly state what is the exact problem, and it's a bit tricky to *guess* how the same syntax worked with just a little bit older version.

I took a guess and removed final comma (after the definition of last `PERSON_AGE BIGINT` column), and it started to work again.

I would love to understand what really causes this exception, behind the scenes. I can't really see any transitive dependencies changing in the project, when upgrading `spring-boot-starter-parent`, to blame any particular library or `.jar`.. yet, something *has to be* causing this exception, and I would like to understand - what does.

I've tested both syntaxes (with and without final comma ",") and both work just fine, as a standalone SQL query, in an SQL shell; however, it doesn't work in the scenario described above.

Would anyone shed some more light on this?

Appreciations.

Comment: What's the actual H2 version being used with both `spring-boot-starter-parent` versions?

Comment: I couldn't find any H2 dependency in `spring-boot-starter-parent`, but I've looked through the logs, and in both cases of `spring-boot-starter-parent` (2.1.1 and 2.3.3), log prints the same: `Database: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb (H2 1.4)`. In case of 2.3.3, though, it adds "Flyway upgrade recommended: H2 1.4.200 is newer than this version of Flyway and support has not been tested.".

Comment: Now I found something digging deeper in parent pom. `<h2.version>1.4.197</h2.version>` for `2.1.1.RELEASE` and `<h2.version>1.4.200</h2.version>` for `2.3.3.RELEASE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

H2 [dropped support for trailing commas](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/commit/7bd5f299bbd937847eb94a8d313db07ad3dd94a5) in 1.4.200. Spring Boot [upgraded to H2 1.4.200](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18593) in 2.1.10 and 2.2.1 and, at the time of writing, it has been the default version of H2 in all Spring Boot releases since then. When you upgrade to Spring Boot 2.3.3 you are also upgrading to H2 1.4.200 so the trailing commas in your migration are no longer support.

If you're curious where these versions are coming from, they're inherited via `spring-boot-starter-parent` which uses `spring-boot-dependencies` as its parent. `spring-boot-dependencies` contains dependency management for numerous Spring projects and third-party dependencies, including H2. The default versions for any given version of Spring Boot are included in the reference documentation:

- [Dependency versions in 2.1.1.RELEASE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html)
- [Dependency versions in 2.3.3.RELEASE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/appendix-dependency-versions.html)

Comment: Shouldn't project's `pom.xml` override `spring-boot-starter-parent`, by the way?

Comment: It does, but you haven't specified a version on the H2 dependency in your pom so the version defined in the parent's dependency management is used.

Comment: Pff.. I missed that part.. my bad. Thank you very much, Andy. Just as a side-note, I think, it would've been better to explicitly throw this with a message like "H2 1.4.200 does not support trailing commas anymore". I think it can be narrowed down when parsing the SQL query. :)

Comment: I agree, but that's out of Spring Boot's control as it's H2 that's throwing the exception. It would have been nice if they'd introduced a specific error for this case rather than using [42001 which is for any invalid SQL](https://www.h2database.com/javadoc/org/h2/api/ErrorCode.html#c42001).

Comment: True, and I'm not referring to Spring Boot's people with that.. at the end of the day, they're just consuming H2 dependency, provided by 3rd party. It can be really confusing when dealing with a large SQL scripts - what is that syntax error about? this was a sample of few lines.. but in case of a real projects, "Syntax Error" is really general and broad, and if possible (and it is possible in this case), it's much better to have it more self-explanatory.